# Is it possible to create a Slack bot that would add an animation snippet within a slack message?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, slack-api

I'm not a techie and don't know how to code, unfortunately...wanted to see if I could educate myself on how to build a Slack bot by asking the dev community. If I could have a step by step on what it takes to build something like this, it would make things much easier.

1. Pull a Slack user avatar into a message window within a Slack channel
2. Trigger animation with user avatar detection (like a Santa hat that floats from the side right on top of user avatar)
3. Puts an animation on top of user avatar, completes an action and loops

Thank you

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO.  Maybe https://slack.com/help/articles/115005265703-Create-a-bot-for-your-workspace is a good starting point

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. I was just looking for something that would explain the process a bit more in depth from the technical perspective. Slack Help Center certainly helps but not when it comes to animation creation and connecting the two.